# Syntax error while creating a new empty list in python3

Tags: python, list, syntax, python-3.7

So I'm a complete newbie and here is a script that I wrote in python3 to find all the numbers smaller than a given integer which are divisible by 3 and 5:

```
def check_divisible():  
 num=(int(input("Give me a number: "))
 result = [ ]
 for i in range(num):
    if i<= num and num%3==0 and num%5==0:
        result.append(i)
        i+=1
 print("Numbers which are smaller than the given and divisile by both 3 and 5 are: ",result)
```

Whenever I execute the code I get a syntax error in line 3. How can I fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Count how many `(` and `)` you have on line 2. Also note, you don't need `i += 1`. `i` will be automatically incremented due to you looping over a `range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def check_divisible():
    num = int(input("Give me a number: "))
    result = []
    for i in range(1, num):
        if i%3==0 and i%5==0:
            result.append(i)
  print(result)
```

Comment: Can you please explain why I can't start from 0 ?

Comment: You could if you want it in the list. Just thought normally you wouldn't put 0 in a list of divisible numbers.

Comment: so I tested your code and the bug was fixed but the result returned is an empty list. May I ask why is that?

Comment: What num are you using. Lowest common multiple of 3 and 5 is 15. So you need at least 16 as the input.

Comment: so here is the traceback : python temp.py
Give me a number: 26
Numbers below the given and divisible by both 3 and 5 are:  []

Comment: is it a bug of the script or is it just my laptop not working properly ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def check_divisible():  
 num= int(input("Give me a number: "))
 result = []
 for i in range(num):
    if i<= num and num%3==0 and num%5==0:
        result.append(i)
        i+=1
 print("Numbers which are smaller than the given and divisile by both 3 and 5 are: ",result)
```

Just some parentheses issues. Fixed the code.